# How to not notify reviewers Github pull request?

Tags: git, github

Suppose I am working on branch called `feature_one`, and I have an existing pull request on Github, someone comments on it and requests changes.

So I amend the commit in `feature_one` with the change and do `git push origin -f feature_one` so it goes to the remote branch. However, I don't want it reviewed yet, but it still notifies reviewers, how do I avoid this?

In other words, how do I preview the whole pull request and manually send it for review rather than auto send with a push to remote?

Comment: You already asked for the pull request on `feature_one`, so this train has already left the station. If you don't want the review, withdraw it.

Comment: You have to convert back your PR as a draft (see my answer)

Answer (score 6):

You have to convert back you pull request to a draft to prevent reviewer to be notified.

[image]

> a draft pull request will suppress notifications to those reviewers until it is marked as ready for review.

Source: https://github.blog/2019-02-14-introducing-draft-pull-requests/

Answer (score 0):

You asked

> How to not notify reviewers Github pull request?

-- Never.

Because, If you don't notify reviewer, they cannot know when to check your source code.

Just for fun: Don't send pull request, your reviewer will not receive any notification.

Comment: Right but I think they get a notification if i push to the remote branch, which i want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether the project defines any rules regarding PRs and reviews. It's possible you aren't the first person in such a situation and there's already a process to handle it.

Here's one possible approach:

Create another branch, work on it while the PR is not ready for review just to save the progress. Once the work is ready, merge<sup>*</sup> it into the original branch you opened the pull request from, which will notify the reviewer.

<sup>*</sup> You can also just `reset --hard` the branch to the working one.

Comment: Is there a way I can preview my full PR? I know archanist has a similar feature with `arc diff --preview`

Comment: No direct way as far as I know. You can always open a PR in your own fork, though.

Comment: You have to convert back your PR as a draft (see my answer)

Comment: @Philippe: Hm, we use GitHub for work and we haven't noticed this feature yet. It seems we should update our processes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't how it happened that I commented on your answer meanwhile I wanted to comment on the question. But if it could have helped ;) To be frank, I didn't knew it either but I quickly checked because it seems to me that it could makes sense. I quickly searched and it seems to be the case. But it needs to be verified......

Answer (score 0):

hmm, you can update your PR to remove reviewer, then add they back when you're confident that PR ready. If you not confident then I prefer you decline your PR then recreate when you confident your code OK

But once you commit and make a PR, should test everything both (unit test & automation/manual test all scenario). At least your PR should not have bad mistakes, you can install sonarlint to help some general issues